# Choosing a value from Aria Control Dropdown using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a click and select value from dropwdown for this HTML code.

I'm unable to make the click change.

I tried `getelementbyID` and `getelementbyclassname`.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/submit" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="project-form"> 
   <div class="form-fields"> 
     <h1>Basics</h1> 
   <div class="control-groups"> 
   <label for="project_requestor">Primary Delivery Contact / Project Requestor 
   <span>*</span></label> 
   <select class="required tooltip dropdown" data-placeholder="Select Sub- Category" 
id="project_requestor" name="project_requestor" data-type="contact_name"> 
        <option value="0">Select Requestor</option> 
   </select> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using IE and that you have a proper wait before attempting these i.e.

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

To click dropdown:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#project_requestor").click
```

To select first option:

```
ie.document.querySelector("#project_requestor [value='0']").Selected = True
```

The # is a css id selector. The [] is a css attribute selector. These target the elements by the css of the page.

Comment: <span title="Select Requestor" class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-project_requestor-container">Select Requestor</span>

This is the code upon inspect element. I tried above method but it didnt work. Also tried various combinations e.g getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname which failed. Please help QHarr

Comment: That has a different id and would be #select2-project_requestor-container  inside querySelector. It looks like a click element to allow you to then make an option selection.

Comment: i tried this different id still nothing happened. im just able to type text in textbox by getelementbyid but not click via queryselector or getelementbyid or classname

Comment: Dear Qharr. Is it possible if you can navigate to this site "https://mc.wpress.dk/" and try to automate the dropdown using macro and share me the code if it works. It would be very kind of you. You need to create a account with Podio, which you will be directed to after you click "Authenticate with Podio" button.